# How can I get a layer with the same size of the original input using deconv2d in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

```py
u1 = deconv2d(c2)
```

`c2` is the previous layer, `u1` is getting double size after applying this deconv2 function, I want to apply this function but want to get the same size output as input.

Comment: Can you show how you created deconv2d?

Comment: just use the built in function  as shown in question, i doubles the size of c2

Answer (score 0):

solved the issue,

these are the change in defination of code

```
def deconv2d(layer_input):
            """Layers used during upsampling"""
            u = UpSampling2D(size=2)(layer_input)
            u = Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same')(u)
            u = Activation('relu')(u)
            return u

size=1 instead of 2
```